# Git pull command from different user

Tags: git, github

I am working with my friend on a project the code of which is on Git. If I need to pull the changes from my friend's machine, can I pull it from my username/password using the following command without any issue?

```
git pull https://myusername@github.com/abc/theproject.git
```

Comment: Are you trying to pull your friend's changes directly from his machine without going through GitHub?

Comment: @Chris, Yes basically our site is deployed on his machine. I have made some changes and pushed it to github. Now I want deploy the changes by pulling from github as my friend is out for vacations for now.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

This command will help to pull from the repository as the different user:

```
git pull https://myusername@github.com/projectfolder/projectname.git master
```

It is a workaround, when you are using same machine that someone else used before you, and had saved credentials

Comment: it's woks for me!

Answer (score 39):

Was looking for the solution of a similar problem. Thanks to the answer provided by Davlet and Cupcake
I was able to solve my problem.

Posting this answer here since I think this is the intended question

So I guess generally the problem that people like me face is what to do when a repo is cloned by another user on a server and that user is no longer associated with the repo.

How to pull from the repo without using the credentials of the old user ?

You edit the .git/config file of your repo.

and change

```
url = https://<old-username>@github.com/abc/repo.git/
```

to

```
url = https://<new-username>@github.com/abc/repo.git/
```

After saving the changes, from now onwards git pull will pull data while using credentials of the new user.

I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem

Comment: Even better: you leave the username out of the URL, so it will ask you for a username when pulling.

Comment: i did the same. left the url out of the url, like so instead of editing directly: git remote set-url origin https://git.mycompany.com/scm/myproj.git ... then made sure all users (their linux group) have access to write to the project and .git folder (otherwise the other user will get an error saying can't update .git/HEAD for example when they run 'git pull'

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little unclear, but if what you're doing is trying to get your friend's latest changes, then typically what your friend needs to do is to push those changes up to a remote repo (like one hosted on GitHub), and then you fetch or pull those changes from the remote:

1. Your friend pushes his changes to GitHub:

   ```
   git push origin <branch>
   ```
2. Clone the remote repository if you haven't already:

   ```
   git clone https://myusername@github.com/abc/theproject.git
   ```
3. Fetch or pull your friend's changes (unnecessary if you just cloned in step #2 above):

   ```
   git fetch origin
   git merge origin/<branch>
   ```

   Note that `git pull` is the same as doing the two steps above:

   ```
   git pull origin <branch>
   ```

### See Also

- [Pro Git § 2.5 Git Basics - Working with Remotes - Fetching and Pulling from Your Remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Fetching-and-Pulling-from-Your-Remotes)
- [Official documentation for `git pull`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html)

Comment: The site is deployed on my friend's machine. I have made some changes on my machine and pushed it to github. Now I want deploy the changes by pulling on my friend's machine because he is out for vacations.

Comment: @MohsinInayatKhan so then log into your friend's machine and do step #3 like I pointed out above, **assuming that that is how your deployment process works**. Why is your site deployed on ***your friend's machine*** and not on some production server? What kind of machine is your friend using, a laptop? If he is, that would not be a very safe or reliable way to host a business website.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. The following command worked for me.
git pull https://myusername@github.com/abc/theproject.git master

Comment: @MohsinInayatKhan you can post that as an answer.